# How can I define m loops inside each other automatically to generate a n^m row table with all unique combinations?

Tags: python-3.x

There are m states that each n items can have, we can code n loops inside each other with m iterations, but the problem is that we need add another loop when n changed to n+1...

the table that i want to generate for n=3, m=2 is as follows:

```
m = 2
n = 3
for i in range(m):
        for j in range(m):
            for k in range(m):
                print(i+1, j+1, k+1)

1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

when n = 4, m = 2

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            for l in range(2):
                print(i+1, j+1, k+1, l+1)
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 2
1 2 1 1
1 2 1 2
1 2 2 1
1 2 2 2
2 1 1 1
2 1 1 2
2 1 2 1
2 1 2 2
2 2 1 1
2 2 1 2
2 2 2 1
2 2 2 2
```

how can write a code that can work with any m and n values?

Comment: thanks, but that's not the problem. how can i define these loops to generate another loop inside the last loop when n changes to n + 1. in this for example 3 to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the correct tool for the job (in this case `itertools.product`) then you get a dynamic solution:

```
from itertools import product

m = 2
n = 3

print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, prod)) for prod in product(range(1, m + 1), repeat=n)))
```

Outputs

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Now in case something changes all that needs to be changed are the values of `m` and `n`.